# Is there any way to rotate an Image on Android without loading whole image to the memory?

Tags: android, bitmap, image-rotation

I want to rotate an Image on sdcard on Android. I can do this by creating a Bitmap and by the help of `postRotate(float)` method of the `Matrix` class. What is the most efficient way to do this on Android?

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible with the Android SDK. Best chance is to load a scaled bitmap that fits the size you need to display and rotate it.

Answer (score 0):

It's exactly the way you are doing it.
How in hell would you like to manipulate data without modifying it? That is what you are basically trying to do. :)
You want to do it without loading the data into ram. That's basically possible, but it would take hours as hard disk access is so much slower than accessing ram/caches.

Comment: You don't need to load all your data into memory to manipulate it in general. The point of the question is if it's possible to rotate the image without loading **all** the image into memory.